# Prevent double click except when validation error

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, double-click

```
<p:commandButton id="checkout" 
   value="Checkout" 
   action="#{checkoutBean.checkout}" 
   update="@form"
   onclick="setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'' + this.id + '\').disabled=true;', 50);"/>
```

On my checkout button I use the timeout hack to prevent double clicks...
However if the validation fails (e.g. the user puts in an invalid card number), the button is disabled and they can't enter the correct details.

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent having duplicate calls to the checkout you can use `onstart` and `oncomplete`,

```
onstart="PF('checkoutWV').disable()" 
oncomplete="PF('checkoutWV').enable()"
```

`checkoutWV` is the widgetVar of the button.